# Clarification on updating path in bashrc

Tags: linux, path, git, bashrc

I am following a [tutorial](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/) on installing git on a shared host and need some clarification if possible.

I have access to the GCC

```
jpols@MrComputer ~
$ ssh nookdig1@***.***.**.*'gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.'
```

and can edit the bashrc file:

```
jpols@MrComputer ~
$ vi .bashrc
```

However I dont really understand how to read if the path has been added correctly:

> Update your $PATH None of this will work if you don’t update the $PATH
>   environment variable. In most cases, this is set in .bashrc. Using
>   .bashrc instead of .bash_profile updates $PATH for interactive and
>   non-interactive sessions–which is necessary for remote Git commands.
>   Edit .bashrc and add the following line:
>
> export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH

I added the above to the file and saved but it goes on to say

> Be sure ‘~/bin’ is at the beginning since $PATH is searched from left
>   to right;

But ~/bin is different to the given path. Could someone please explain what this means?

After adding the Path as specified the output is:

```
jpols@MrComputer ~
$ source ~/.bashrc

jpols@MrComputer ~
$ echo $PATH
/home/jpols/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.dnx/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/cygdrive/c/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.13:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2:/cygdrive/c/Ruby22-x64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/jpols/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/jpols/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/c/Users/jpols/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/jpols/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Nmap
```

Just comparing the first part:

Tutorial: `/home/joe/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`

Mine: `/home/jpols/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/`

They are different so before I go on I am hoping someone can explain what I am trying to achieve and how to do it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '~' character is used to indicate the current user's home directory on UNIX systems.  Because the username on your computer is different from the one on the machine used in the tutorial you referred to, different directory paths have been appended to the PATH variable. By using '~' one does not have to manually enter one's username for referring to the user home directory, which allowed the creator of the tutorial to create code which makes the PATH variable look into both of your home directories, even though both of your systems have different paths to your home directories. (e.g. `/home/joe/bin` and `/home/jpols/bin` are different directories, but `~/bin` can be used to refer to both, as the '~' will be expanded to the correct path by the system)

Comment: You probably should *not* have / in your path: that's the root directory and there is no executable file in the root directory (usually).

Comment: Sorry if your referring to the last / that just abbrieviated from `home/jpols/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/...... ` What I meant was how my path is `local bin usr bin` but the example is `local bin bin usr bin`. Is it ok if this is different? I am right that the : signifies the end of a path?